# Why does "wc -c" print a value of one more with echo?

Tags: text-processing, echo, wc

When running

```
echo abcd | wc -c
```

it returns `5`.
But the word `abcd` is only 4 characters long.

Is `echo` printing some special character after the word `abcd`?

And can I prevent `echo` from printing that?

Comment: [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/52934)

Comment: Please be aware that `wc -c` does not tell you how many characters something is; it only tells how many bytes it is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`echo` print newline (`\n`) at end of line

```
echo abcd | xxd
0000000: 6162 6364 0a          abcd.
```

With some `echo` implementations, you can use `-n` :

> `-n` do not output the trailing newline

and test:

```
echo -n abcd | wc -c
4
```

With some others, you need the `\c` escape sequence:

> [`\c`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html):  Suppress the `<newline>` that otherwise follows the final argument in the output. All characters following the `'\c'` in the arguments shall be ignored.

```
echo -e 'abcd\c' | wc -c
4
```

Portably, use `printf`:

```
printf %s abcd | wc -c
4
```

(note that `wc -c` counts bytes, not characters (though in the case of `abcd` they are generally equivalent). Use `wc -m` to count characters).

Comment: Note that the point is that with some `echo` implementations (all Unix compliant ones at least), it's `echo 'abcd\c'` that outputs `abcd` alone. `echo -e 'abcd\c'` in Unix-compliant `echo` implementations would output `-e abcd`.

Answer (score 5):

If you run `echo` without the `-n` option,
it writes a newline character after the arguments. 
Otherwise, if you typed `echo foo`,
your next shell prompt would appear to the right of the `foo`. 
So `wc` is counting the newline.

> How can I prevent `echo` from printing that?

```
echo -n abcd | wc -c
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `echo` will print a [newline character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (`\n`) after the string (which is why you see the shell prompt on the next line instead of the same line where `abcd` is printed.)

You can try adding a `-n` parameter to `echo` to disable the trailing newline character.

```
echo -n abcd | wc -c
4
```